# What options are there to get a front panel for a 24-pin Front Panel header on a Intel Server Motherboard

Tags: intel

How do I use third-party front panels to go with the 24-pin SSI-compliant front-panel connectors for Intel servers?

I am trying to use some refurbished server chassis. The front control panel (one which displays the status LEDs and has the power switch) is missing on some of them. I could not find any replacements.

Is there any other solution to this apparently trivial problem? I do not mind using splitter cables to connect to the individual controls on the 24 pin connector header. The Intel motherboard is well documented on this front. The pin-out of the 24-pin control header is described in detail.

I do not mind not having all the panel controls working... At least the standard ones such as HDD display LED, NIC LED, Power switch should be there on the panel.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A lot of third party front panels will have individual connectors for each of the front panel items - ie 2 pin header connections for HDD light, reset button, Power light, etc. For some reason, the on board speaker is normally a four pin connector despite only using two cables!

As long as you know the layout of the header on the motherboard, you can just plug these items directly into it.

Here's an example of what I mean:

[image]
<sub>(source: [tomshardware.com](http://img.tomshardware.com/us/2002/09/18/building_your_own_pc/panel_leitungen.jpg))</sub>

Comment: Do you know of any third party panel providers? Had a tough time locating any!

Comment: To be honest, you may need to look at a whole new case. Normally, the front panel of a particular case would only be compatible with the case it was designed for. Dependent on budget, you could either look at a new case, or perhaps just get an old server/workstation off ebay and transfer the components to that. Just one other thing to bear in mind, the LEDs will need the correct polarity - ie it matters which way round the header is plugged in. Power switch, reset switch, etc won't matter - they can be plugged in either way round.

Comment: I think I am just going to get some LEDs and Push button switch and make a front panel and somehow fix it on the chassis. A lot cheaper option and as I have more than one of these sitting around, this will be a more general solution... Your answer was helpful to make things simple in my mind.